# T-SQL Methods to check for value or assign null

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Are these all valid methods of checking that a value exists and assigning null?

```
Insert ...
    Select 
        ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),''), 
        COALESCE(N' ', N' '),
        '' STATUS,
```

This is for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Good information about `COALESCE` and `ISNULL` is at SQL Server Pro [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull) and MSDN Blogs [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx).

Comment: You want NULLIF()

Comment: `ISNULL(X, Y)` is identical to `COALESCE(X, Y)`, however `COALESCE` is handy because it allows you to add more values than just two.  I'm not sure what else you are asking, however.  Is your `'' STATUS,` line relevant to the question?

Comment: Are you trying to check for a null value or assign a null value?

Comment: If a column is null, i need to assign a space to it because the table definition is not null.